# Adding Unselectable controls to RibbonMenuButton

Tags: wpf, xaml, ribbon

I am working on a WPF project and I started developing the `Ribbon` area. I just put a `RibbonMenuButton` and added three `RibbonTextBox` inside of it. I want these TextBoxes to retrieve some data from the user. Everything is fine so far.

```
<rb:RibbonMenuButton LargeImageSource="/image.png" Label="Settings"   >

    <rb:RibbonTextBox Label="Field 01:" Text="{Binding Field01 }" />
    <rb:RibbonTextBox Label="Field 02:" Text="{Binding Field02 }" />
    <rb:RibbonTextBox Label="Field 03:" Text="{Binding Field03 }" />

</rb:RibbonMenuButton>
```

My problem is that **the `RibbonTextBox` becomes a menu item, i.e. I can click it and select it.**

But I want to avoid this behavior, I just want to have an **"unselectable"** `RibbonTextBox`.

**Is there a way to achieve that?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [the solution here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/adc660c6-4b09-4e4d-a9d0-3e8f5288c47a):

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type rb:RibbonMenuItem}">
     <Setter Property="Template">
         <Setter.Value>
             <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type rb:RibbonMenuItem}">
                 <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" 
                     Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" Grid.Column="1" 
                     ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" 
                     ContentSource="Header" 
                     Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                     RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
                     VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
             </ControlTemplate>
         </Setter.Value>
     </Setter>
 </Style>
```

This works pretty well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Those are typically called `Labels`.  But in lieu of using the appropriate control, the `RibbonTextBox` has both a `IsReadOnly` propery, which will leave it selectable (ie. for copy/paste) but not editable.  Or `IsEnabled` which will make it completely non-interactive.

I think the `IsEnabled` will also prevent you from being able to click on it at all, but I'm not 100% sure on that.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I just tried what you suggest but, even disabled, it continues being selectable

Comment: @Dante When you say selectable, do you mean just that you can click on the menu item?

Comment: @Dante I don't think you can do that with the `RibbonTextBox` because it's not aware of the menu it's in, so it has no way of telling the menu "make me not selectable".  Any reason not to use a standard `RibbonMenuItem`?